# UserPrincipal.Current throws COMException from one day to the next

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, userprincipal

This morning I started noticing some problems with several of my programs regarding Active Directory read operations. I noticed that all those applications (client and server) use the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal` class for those read operations, while the programs still running correctly use `System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher`.

So in order to narrow the problem down, I built the following, very simple console application

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //this works great
        Console.WriteLine($"Enviroment.Username:{Environment.UserName}");

        //this works great
        PrincipalContext pcFull = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "my.company.de", "dc=my,dc=company,dc=de");
        UserPrincipal upPrincipalContextFull = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pcFull, Environment.UserName);

        //this doesn't work at all
        //Exception: “The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist”
        PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
        UserPrincipal upPrincipalContext = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, Environment.UserName);

        //this doesn't either, same exception
        UserPrincipal upCurrent = UserPrincipal.Current;
        
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

As you can see in the comments, the two latter operations will fail on every Computer in the domain i tested it on, even though they worked perfectly for several years. The following Exception occurs when I call `UserPrincipal.Current`or `UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, Environment.UserName);` without specifying the Container in the PrincipalContext:

`System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: “The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist”`

Here is what I know:

- none of the applications that suddenly stopped working received an update within the last two weeks
- all of those applications, the `UserPrincipal.Current`-Property and the `UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity`-Method worked perfectly yesterday
- Workstations did not receive Windows or .Net updates in the last week
- the phenomenon does not relate to a single workstation, user or OS, but occures for a lot of different users, on a lot of different machines running Windows 7 or 10.
- Domain Controllers received updates a week ago. Apparently one of those updates has a known issue about LDAP queries: [Due to a defect in WLDAP32.DLL, applications that perform LDAP referral chasing can consume too many dynamic TCP ports](http://Due%20to%20a%20defect%20in%20WLDAP32.DLL,%20applications%20that%20perform%20LDAP%20referral%20chasing%20can%20consume%20too%20many%20dynamic%20TCP%20ports). It seems unlikely that this is the reason for the sudden failures because a) that patch was installed a week ago and the Problems only occurred today and b) the suggested Workarounds from Microsoft (restarting Services) don't have any effect

What might cause such a behavior "overnight"? If it really is related to a Windows update, other users will soon be experiencing this bug too!

I can obviously build Workarounds, so I don't have to use the failing methods and properties, but I still have to know why it stopped working in the first place.

### Edit

To start with,  it would be useful to understand the difference between
`public PrincipalContext(ContextType contextType);` and `public PrincipalContext(ContextType contextType, string name, string container);`. The PrincipalContext constructed without container still has to obtain that container somehow, doesn't it?

Comment: Did you find out why the COM exception was happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the `PrincipalContext` searches in the "OU=Computers"-Container.
This fails if the reading permission is not set for the Container and will throw a COM Exception.

Comment: What all permissions need to be setup?

Comment: What permission needed for same then ?